# How do I keep a dropdown div onscreen by placing above or below a related control?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, html, drop-down-menu

Should be a simple one, but my searches are coming up with unrelated problems.

Basically I have created a custom DropDown CheckBoxList for ASP.Net.

It uses nested Divs like this simplified example (the list/table itself is generated by an ASP.Net CheckBoxList):

```
<DIV class="dropDownComboxBoxList">
    <DIV class="dropDownControl">
        <DIV class="dropDownLeft">
            <INPUT class="dropDownEdit" type="text" > 
        </DIV>
        <DIV class="dropDownRight">
            <IMG class="img-swap" src="/Images/DropDown_off.gif"> 
        </DIV>
    </DIV>
    <DIV style="MIN-WIDTH: 300px; DISPLAY: none; MAX-HEIGHT: 150px" class="dropDownDiv">
        <TABLE style="WIDTH: 100%; HEIGHT: 40px" id="checkBoxList" class="dropDownTable">
            <TBODY>
                <TR>
                    <TD class="firstCheck">
                        <INPUT class="dropDownCheck" type="checkbox">
                        <LABEL class="dropDownLabel">All</LABEL>
                    </TD>
                </TR>
                <TR class="checkSel">
                    <TD>
                        <INPUT class="dropDownCheck" type="checkbox">
                        <LABEL class="dropDownLabel">Item 0</LABEL>
                    </TD>
                </TR>
            </TBODY>
        </TABLE>
    </DIV>
</DIV>
```

The control appears like this:

[image]

The problem is that ***when the Text control is below the middle of the screen, the popup Div should appear above the Text control***, like any other standard dropdown e.g.:

[image]

### What is the easiest way to do this in JQuery/CSS?

**Update - my first lame test attempt looks like this (but the visual effect of it jumping up is bad):**

```
function DropDown(id, idt) 
    $(id).toggle('fast', function () {
        if ($(id).css('display') != 'none') {
            var pos = $(id).height() + $(idt).height();
            $(id).css("margin-top", -pos+"px");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is this not really just about positioning one element respective to another element? Not so much about programatically achieving something?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: That may well be the case, but whether it appears above or below depends on the screen position of the text box... does that not require some sort of code intervention? Happy to accept a JQuery/CSS answer (will alter tags)

Comment: So you want to change the position of the container based on the window's scroll bar? Not just keep it appended to the top of the list always?

Comment: Correct. Hence: "when the Text control is below the middle of the screen".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This actually works, but I would like to see it improved if possible to use best practices etc:**

```
function DropDown(id, idt) {
    var dd = $(id);
    var tb = $(idt);
    var pos = (tb.position().top > $(window).height() / 2 + $(document).scrollTop()) ? -(dd.height() + tb.height() + 9) : 0;
    dd.css("margin-top", pos + "px");
    dd.toggle(1, function () {
        ... Do more stuff in here
    });
}
```

Problems remaining include:

- You can't animate the toggle (e.g. with "fast" as it causes the
  animation to fly up).
- It needs a correction to the position offset to cater for the padding of the parent divs.